# Django i try to use reverse function and i got NoReverseMatch

Tags: django, web, django-views, reverse

i am a new at Django framework.
and i follow of some guide on udemy and do step by step
but something go wrong.

i open startapp call 'accounts', and then i have file call urls.py
here is what i have.

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'accounts'

urlpatterns = [
    path("<int:month>", views.monthly_num),
    path("<str:month>", views.monthly_str, name='monthly-acc'),
]
```

and in views.py file i want to do reverse and to do redirect.

```
from django.shortcuts import render 
from django.http import HttpResponseNotFound 
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect 
from django.urls import reverse

# Create your views here.

months = {
    "january": "Hello january",
    "febuary": "Hello febuary",
    "march": "Hello march",
    "april": "Hello april", }


def monthly_str(request, month):
    try:
        text_month = months[month]
        return HttpResponse("<h1>"+text_month+"</h1>")
    except:
        return HttpResponseNotFound("THIS NOT A MONTH!")


def monthly_num(request, month):
    monthly = list(months.keys())
    if month > len(monthly) or month <= 0:
        return HttpResponseNotFound("<h1>NO GOOD</h1>")

    redirect_month = monthly[month-1]
    redirect_path = reverse('monthly-acc', args=[redirect_month]) # HERE I GOT THE ERROR.
    return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_path)
```

so what i try to do

i have the local url for example: http://mypro:9000/acc/1
i want to redirect to http://mypro:9000/acc/january

and i got this page error.

[image: The Error Page]

Comment: Did you specify an `app_name` in the `urls.py`?

Comment: yes i did 
i need to delete it? @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: no, then it is `reverse('app_name:monthly-acc', ...)`, so you prefix with the `app_name`.

Comment: now when i refresh i got "'app_name' is not a registered namespace", but when i delete the app_name from urls.py its actually work. @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: the `app_name` in the `reverse` should be replaced with the value you assigned to the `app_name` variable...